# Is it possible to define property for inline Gradle task

Tags: gradle

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html shows example how to define task property via `extends DefaultTask`.

It is possible to define task property directly with task inline definition syntax, like:

```
task collectSqlFiles {
    FileCollection sqlFiles
    doLast {
        sqlFiles = fileTree("$rootDir/function", sqlFilePatt) +
                 fileTree("$rootDir/maintenance", sqlFilePatt) +
                 fileTree("$rootDir/monitoring", sqlFilePatt) +
                 fileTree("$rootDir/view", sqlFilePatt)
    }
}

task printSqlFiles {
    dependsOn collectSqlFiles

    doLast {
        // Got:  Could not get unknown property 'sqlFiles' for task ':collectSqlFiles'
        // of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
        collectSqlFiles.sqlFiles.forEach { logger.lifecycle("sqlFile: {}", it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `ExtensionAware` Gradle domain objects intrinsically have an extension named “ext” of [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html).

Inline `task` is [DefaultTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) and it implements  `ExtensionAware`.

So solution is:

```
task collectSqlFiles {
    FileCollection sqlFiles
    doLast {
        // TAKE LOOK to "ext."
        ext.sqlFiles = fileTree("$rootDir/function", sqlFilePatt) +
                 fileTree("$rootDir/maintenance", sqlFilePatt) +
                 fileTree("$rootDir/monitoring", sqlFilePatt) +
                 fileTree("$rootDir/view", sqlFilePatt)
    }
}

task printSqlFiles {
    dependsOn collectSqlFiles

    doLast {
        collectSqlFiles.sqlFiles.forEach { logger.lifecycle("sqlFile: {}", it) }
    }
}
```

Take look to official [Dynamic Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#N18C07) section.